# with php explode first variable is untrimmable

Tags: php, explode

i have two files, b.txt:

```
&first = cjnk1 
&second = dcnksj2
&third = cd3
&fourth = cdln4
```

and a.php:

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents("b.txt");
$rows=explode("\n", $data);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $temp=explode(" = ",$row);
    $info[ltrim($temp[0],"&")]=$temp[1];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo $info["&first"];
?>
```

and the output is

```
Array
(
    [﻿&first] => cjnk1
    [second] => dcnksj2
    [third] => cd3
    [fourth] => cdln4
)
```

whats wrong with the first index?? even if i use it, its unechoable..

Comment: Maybe there’s something before the `&` like non-printable characters.

Comment: Probably, there's some escape-char before `&`. use `var_dump($temp[0]);` to see exactly what it is.

Comment: its string(9) "&first"

Comment: Your script works fine. Maybe there's BOM or something else in the head of your file, please don't use Notepad on Windows.

Comment: I'm betting on a BOM at the beginning of the file (google it).

Comment: `"&first"` should be `string(6)` -- there's something extra there.

Comment: in hex editor there is some FFFE, but how can i cut it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove the `BOM` via PHP:

```
$BOM = substr($txt, 0, 3);

if ( $BOM == pack("CCC", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF) ) {
    $txt = substr($txt, 3);
}
```

**Update**

As `deceze` point it out, this should works fine also (but I didn't checked it out yet, please let me know if there were anything wrong with that)

```
$BOM = substr($txt, 0, 3);

/* "Double Quotes" are important */
if ( $BOM == "\xEF\xBB\xBF" ) {
    $txt = substr($txt, 3);
}
```

Comment: Generally yes, but you could more easily write a BOM as `"\x.."` string literal... :)

Comment: @deceze thanks for the info, but what does it mean `..`? will you give a hint for the further reading, thanks.

Comment: I mean: `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"`. That's a string literal for a BOM. No need for `pack`.

Comment: @deceze oh, got it! I was looking at the `pack` manual to see what's that! thanks again for the info!

Comment: @deceze I've updated my answer to reflect your point as well, but is it better to use `===`?

Comment: @filip welcome! happy to hear that! the `deceze` version probably has less overhead ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `ltrim($temp[0],"&")` with `ltrim($temp[0], "&\x00..\x1F");`. This will remove any reserved ASCII characters (0-31), as well as the ampersand.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $temp=explode(" = ",$row);
    $info[substr($temp[0], 1)]=$temp[1];
}
```